# Problem Running MySQL Script with Airflow MySQL Operator

Tags: airflow

I'm not understanding something about using the MySQL operator to call and a MySQL script with Apache Airflow.

When I run this task...

```
    MySQLTest    = MySqlOperator(
                                task_id='MySQLTest',
                                sql = '/home/user/DBScripts/MySQLScript/SampleMySQLScript.sql',
                                mysql_conn_id = 'mysql_db_connect',                                
                                autocommit = True, 
                                database = 'segments' 
                                )
```

I get this error in traceback...

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: /home/user/DBScripts/MySQLScript/SampleMySQLScript.sql
```

The DAG task runs fine if I provide the entire SQL script as a parameter.

I'm not familiar with Jinja templating.

Is it easier to learn to write my scripts as a Jinja template?  Should I import the text of the script and assign it to a variable that I pass?  Is there a way to write the Airflow task so that it isn't expecting a Jinja template?

Comment: I've ended up storing the scripts as Stored Procedures and using the SQL parameter in the Task to make the Stored Proc Call.   I don't like this answer, but it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message means that the `.sql` file is not found.

Using:

```
MySQLTest = MySqlOperator(
    task_id='MySQLTest',
    sql='test.sql',
    mysql_conn_id='mysql_db_connect',
    autocommit=True,
    database='segments',
    dag=dag
)
```

Where test.sql is located on the same folder as the DAG file works fine:

[image]

If the path of the `.sql` file is not relative to the DAG file you can use `template_searchpath` to define the list of folders (non relative) where jinja will look for the templates.

So Your code could look like:

```
default_args = {  # pylint: disable=invalid-name
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 12, 03),
}
with DAG(
        dag_id='my_sql_dag',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=None,
        template_searchpath=['/home/user/DBScripts/MySQLScript']
) as dag:
    MySQLTest = MySqlOperator(
        task_id='MySQLTest',
        sql='SampleMySQLScript.sql',
        mysql_conn_id='mysql_db_connect',
        autocommit=True,
        database='segments'
    )
```