# How to add database partition based on airflow timestamp

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

Here I am trying to fetch the data from open source and add it to the table as partition based on airflow timestamp. But it raises an airflow exception.

```
def partition_sql(entity_type):
            sql = """
                ALTER TABLE db.table
                ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (airflow_ts='{{ts}}')
                LOCATION 's3://db/table/update/airflow_ts={{ts}}';
            """
        return sql
    
with DAG(parameters)as dag:

    update = DockerOperator(
        task_id='update',
        cmd = 'python script.py 's3://db/table1/update/airflow_ts={{ts}}'
     )
  partition = AWSAthenaOperator(
        task_id='partition',
        query=partition_sql("artist"),
    )


 update >>partition
```

Comment: At what format u need the timestamp?

Comment: ISO format or even just the date would be good

Comment: Can you explain what entity_type is used for? Is it the table name?

Comment: I have to run the same piece of code for different kinds of entities like artist, song etc. Here I have just mentioned for artist type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both `cmd` and `query` fields are templated this should work:

```
items = ["artist"] #add more tables to be created dynamically
with DAG(
        dag_id="dag_name",
        default_args=default_args,
) as dag:
    for item in items:
        command = f'python script.py 's3://db/{item}/update/airflow_ts={{ ds }} '
        update = DockerOperator(
            task_id=f'update_table_{item}',
            cmd=command
        )
        sql = f'ALTER TABLE db.{item} ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (airflow_ts={{ ds }}) LOCATION s3://db/table/update/airflow_ts={{ ds }};'
        partition = AWSAthenaOperator(
            task_id=f'partition_table_{item}',
            query=sql
        )
```

You can change from `{{ ds }}` to any other format of date you'd like. You can view formats available at [macros](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/macros-ref.html) page or customize one of your own.

Note that you don't have to save the SQL in the code here. You can save it in `.sql` files as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59911387/problem-running-mysql-script-with-airflow-mysql-operator/65129370#65129370)